# In Python 3.4.3, How to send flag 'Seen' with IMAP protocol

Tags: python-3.x, email, imap

1. Get Mail list that flag 'UNSEEN'
2. Read each of the mails
3. leave a flag 'Seen' that I manufactured one.

I want to set a mail up flag 'Seen' in my email account.
How can i set up 'Seen' Flag in python.

Do you have any idea?

```
import imaplib

emailConnection = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL() 
emailConnection.login(id, password)

emailConnection.select(configData['email_input_folder']) 

result, data = emailConnection.uid('SEARCH', None, '(UNSEEN)')
uids = data[0].split()
for uid in uids:
    result, data = emailConnection.uid('fetch', uid, '(RFC822)') 
    # ------   data is manufactured.
    result = emailConnection.store(uid, '+FLAGS', '\\Seen')  # << Occured Exception
```

In My Error Message is printed like this.

```
[DEBUG|imap.py:81]2017-02-24 21:43:57,921 > STORE command error: BAD [b'Error in IMAP command STORE: Invalid messageset']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing UID and Sequence Sets.

If you use `UID SEARCH` and `UID FETCH`, you need to use `UID STORE`:

```
result = emailConnection.uid("STORE", uid, '+FLAGS', '\\Seen')
```

Comment: Oh My God, You're awesome genius! Thanks a lot #Max.
If you don't mind, Could you tell me why occur this error?

Comment: Yes, UIDs are much higher than sequence numbers usually: sequence numbers are reused, but UIDs are forever increasing.  Therefore, a UID is likely not to exist a sequence number, and therefore refers to messages that don't exist.  It is giving you an error saying it was a bad message sequence number.

Comment: It's just python API's feature. Isn't it ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. @Max .  Happy Hacking