# I am trying to make a email chatbot but it spams how could i fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp, imap, chatbot

I am trying to build a email chatbot but it has this bug where after it sends the first message, and then gets a response it keeps spamming the answered to the response it got until it gets another response which then it repeats again I was thinking to solve this I should use a variable which detects emails and later down the code a condition that responds only if a email is received, does anyone have any idea on how I could fix this? Thanks

```
def receive_email():
try:
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("smtp.gmail.com")
    mail.login(email_address, email_password)
    mail.select('inbox')
    #searches inbox
    status, data = mail.search(None, 'Recent')
    mail_ids = data[0].split()
    latest_email_id = mail_ids[-1]
    status, data = mail.fetch(latest_email_id, '(RFC822)')
    #gets message
    for response_part in data:
        if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
            msg = email.message_from_bytes(response_part[1])
            sender = msg['from']
            subject = msg['subject']
            if msg.is_multipart():
                for part in msg.get_payload():
                    if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
                        return part.get_payload()
                    message = msg.get_payload()
            
                    return message,
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: ", e)
    print("Could not receive email")
    return None, None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the usual problem for an email autoresponder, if I understand you correctly, and [RFC 3834](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3834) offers good advice.

Since answers should be self-contained I offer a summary:

1. Add the `Auto-Submitted: auto-replied` header field on your outgoing messages. Any value other than `no` will prevent well-written autoresponders from replying to your outgoing messages.
2. [Set the `\answered` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42439401/) on the message you reply to, immediately before you send the reply.
3. Change the search key from `recent` to `unanswered not header "auto-submitted" ""`. `unanswered` means that the search won't match the messages on which you set the `\answered` flag, `not header "auto-submitted" ""` means that you'll not match messages that contain any auto-submitted header field.
4. Direct your replies to the address in `return-path` or `sender`, not the one in `from`. This is a matter of convention. Auto-submitted mail will often have a special `return-path` that points to an address that *never* sends any autoreply.

You may also extend the search key with more details from RFC 3834. The one I suggest should work, but `not header "precedence" "junk"` will for example prevent your code from replying to a bit of autogenerated mail. Sendgrid and its friends also add header fields you may want to look for and exclude.

If the incoming message has headers like this (use the "view headers" function of most mail readers to see it):

```
From: example@example.com
Subject: Weekend
To: srtai22@gmail.com
Message-id: <56451182ae7a62978cd6f6ff06dd21e0@example.com>
```

Then your reply should have headers like this:

```
Return-Path: <>
From: srtai22@gmail.com
To: example@example.com
Auto-Submitted: auto-replied
Subject: Auto: Weekend
References: <56451182ae7a62978cd6f6ff06dd21e0@example.com>
```

There'll be many more fields in both, of course. Your reply's return-path says that nothing should respond automatically, From and To are as expected, auto-submitted specifies what sort of response this is, subject doesn't matter very much but this one's polite and well-behaved, and finally references links to the original message.

Comment: Thank  you for your response, I am trying to implement this steps into my code, however i have some questions, for  "1." just to confirm the "Auto-Submitted: auto-replied" should be in the field the subject field?

Also where you say to change from 'ALL' to 'unanswered' I've done it but the chatbot does not reply at all when I do this any idea what it could be? (I  tried both UNSEEN and UNANSWERD)

And for the return path could show me the code on how that could be implemented as well as giving a brief explanation please. Thanks in advance am still new to working with these libraries.

Comment: Oops, sorry, from `recent` from `unanswered…` in the call to `mail.search`. Auto-submitted should be a separate header field, like From, To and Cc. I'll edit the answer to include a good example, but I can't do that right now.

Comment: Thank you for your response, and just do so when you can please

Comment: I just did. The example is short and shows something good. There are quite a few few ways to make the example a little longer and the responder a little better, but IMNSHO "really short and good enough" is the best kind of example.

Comment: Sorry for the late response,  I managed to integrate the \answered that seemed to be the problem as it now doesn't spam and I also manage to sort out the search criterion, so thanks for the help